# Error in retrieving google fit steps

Tags: google-fit, google-fit-sdk

I am using this code to try and retrieve steps made in the last 14 hours.

```
YApp myApp = (mYApp) ctx;
        mGoogleApiClient = myApp.getMyUser();
        mGoogleApiClient.reconnect();


        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        Date now = new Date();
        cal.setTime(now);
        long endTime = cal.getTimeInMillis();
        cal.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, -16);
        long startTime = cal.getTimeInMillis();

        PendingResult<DataReadResult> pendingResult =
                Fitness.HistoryApi.readData(mGoogleApiClient, new DataReadRequest.Builder()
                                .aggregate(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA, DataType.AGGREGATE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA)
                                .bucketByTime(1, TimeUnit.DAYS)
                                .setTimeRange(startTime, endTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                                .build());

        DataReadResult dataReadResult = pendingResult.await();



        DataSet ds = dataReadResult.getDataSet(DataType.AGGREGATE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA);
```

My datareadresult returns success but when I try and read the results into the dataset I get this error

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Attempting to read data for com.google.step_count.delta, which was not requested
```

I have tried all manner of DataTypes but receive the same error everytime, what am I doing wrong?!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For anyone else that gets frustrated over this :)

```
mYApp myApp = (mYApp) ctx;
        mGoogleApiClient = myApp.getMyUser();
        mGoogleApiClient.reconnect();


        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        Date now = new Date();
        cal.setTime(now);
        long endTime = cal.getTimeInMillis();
        cal.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, -12);
        long startTime = cal.getTimeInMillis();

        PendingResult<DataReadResult> pendingResult =
                Fitness.HistoryApi.readData(mGoogleApiClient, new DataReadRequest.Builder()
                                .aggregate(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA, DataType.AGGREGATE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA)
                                .bucketByTime(1, TimeUnit.DAYS)
                                .setTimeRange(startTime, endTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                                .build());

        DataReadResult dataReadResult = pendingResult.await();



        if (dataReadResult.getBuckets().size() > 0) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Number of returned buckets of DataSets is: "
                    + dataReadResult.getBuckets().size());
            for (Bucket bucket : dataReadResult.getBuckets()) {
                List<DataSet> dataSets = bucket.getDataSets();
                for (DataSet dataSet : dataSets) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Data returned for Data type: " + dataSet.getDataType().getName());
                    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT);

                    for (DataPoint dp : dataSet.getDataPoints()) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "Data point:");
                        Log.i(TAG, "\tType: " + dp.getDataType().getName());
                        Log.i(TAG, "\tStart: " + dateFormat.format(dp.getStartTime(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)));
                        Log.i(TAG, "\tEnd: " + dateFormat.format(dp.getEndTime(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)));
                        for(Field field : dp.getDataType().getFields()) {
                            Log.i(TAG, "\tField: " + field.getName() +
                                    " Value: " + dp.getValue(field));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } else if (dataReadResult.getDataSets().size() > 0) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Number of returned DataSets is: "
                    + dataReadResult.getDataSets().size());
            for (DataSet dataSet : dataReadResult.getDataSets()) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Data returned for Data type: " + dataSet.getDataType().getName());
                SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT);

                for (DataPoint dp : dataSet.getDataPoints()) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Data point:");
                    Log.i(TAG, "\tType: " + dp.getDataType().getName());
                    Log.i(TAG, "\tStart: " + dateFormat.format(dp.getStartTime(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)));
                    Log.i(TAG, "\tEnd: " + dateFormat.format(dp.getEndTime(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)));
                    for (Field field : dp.getDataType().getFields()) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "\tField: " + field.getName() +
                                " Value: " + dp.getValue(field));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Can u give some solution, as dataReadResult.getBuckets() method has been removed from the "DataReadResult" class.

Comment: No it hasn't? https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/fitness/result/DataReadResult.html#getBuckets()

Answer (score 4):

Just to clarify

```
PendingResult<DataReadResult> pendingResult =
            Fitness.HistoryApi.readData(mGoogleApiClient, new DataReadRequest.Builder()
                            .aggregate(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA, DataType.AGGREGATE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA)
                            .bucketByTime(1, TimeUnit.DAYS)
                            .setTimeRange(startTime, endTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                            .build());
```

Retruns a DataReadResult with a list of buckets.

```
PendingResult<DataReadResult> pendingResult =
            Fitness.HistoryApi.readData(mGoogleApiClient, new DataReadRequest.Builder()
                            .read(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA)
                            .setTimeRange(startTime, endTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                            .build());
```

Returns a DataReadResult with a DataSet that can be fetched with

```
dataReadResult.getDataSet(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA);
```